# Group name and description - Powershell

Tags: microsoft-excel, powershell, active-directory

I am by no means a powershell professional and could use a little guidance with something I need to accomplish.

I need to generate a csv from AD that contains the following columns:

Name, Samaccountname, Memberof, and the Member of group description.  Currently I have the first 3 using the following:

```
Import-Csv .\users.csv |
ForEach-Object{
Get-ADUser -Identity $_.samaccountname -Properties *  | Select-Object -Property Name,SamAccountName, @{n='MemberOf'; e= { $_.memberof -replace '^CN=(?<Name>.*?),(?:OU|CN).*$', '${Name}' -join ', ' | Out-String}} | Sort-Object -Property Name
}| Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\xxxx\Membership.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

The trouble I am having is figuring out a way to print out the group descriptions so they are in the same order as the group name.  that way once they are in excel I can use VBA to get them so they arent comma separated and on their own ine in each cell

Any ideas or hints would be helpful

BONUS ROUND:
Will also need to take a specific group name and break it out into its own column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will get you what you want. Feel free to swap the user filter for your users.csv.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * |`
ForEach-Object { `
$FileName = $_.SamAccountName + ".csv" ; `
$FileName ; `
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $_ | `
  Select-Object -Property SamAccountName, name, GroupScope, GroupCategory | `
    Sort-Object -Property SamAccountName | `
      Export-Csv -Path $FileName -Encoding ASCII ; `
 }
```

Each user will get their own CSV with sam/name and groups.

Edit:

This will generate one table with each group, grp description, name and sam on one line.

```
ForEach ($Group in (Get-ADGroup -Filter * -properties *))  { Get-ADGroupMember $Group | Select @{Label="Group";Expression={$Group.Name,$Group.Description}},Name,SamAccountName}
```

Comment: I'll play with that.  But we really need one CSV for all users..  and that wont pull the group description .  I am sure there may be somethings I can pull from that.

But yea one file with Full name, samaccountname, group name, group description

Comment: It's possible to merge them all into one file after they have been created as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27892957/merging-multiple-csv-files-into-one-using-powershell Im sure there is a better answer, but these 2 steps will work

Comment: still the above script doesn't generate the required output.  I can get 3 /4 of the required now i just cant get the description of the group that i am getting by using memberof

Yours is only looking at the group name and not the description and only putting the samaccountname as the name of the file and not in the csv.  

Sorry if that sounded ungrateful just making sure we are on the same page lol

Comment: Lets make it easier and not require them to be on one line each group and descritpion can be on its own line

Comment: drop the edit in and see if that outputs better. It is <group>,<GrpDescr>,<Name>,<sam> iterated over every member of every group